# Swift. Steps from 1h ago

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the step count from CMpedometer from 1h ago.

Once I run the code I get (among other things written) an error in the console and in the label on the screen I get "error" instead of the nuber of steps:

> [Generic] Error on message reply (Connection invalid)
>   2018-03-16 12:37:19.021110+0100
>   [Pedometer] Unable to parse message when checking for availability!

This is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Calculation dates for steps 1h ago
     //date now
let calendar = Calendar.current //calendar now, to be used in calculating the h in the past
let beforeDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: Date())

let pedometer = CMPedometer() //define pedometer

pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: beforeDate!, to: Date(), withHandler: { (pedometerData, error) in
                if let pedData = pedometerData{
                    self.dateLabel.text = "Steps:\(pedData.numberOfSteps)"
                }else {
                    self.dateLabel.text = "error)"
                    print(beforeDate)

                }
    })
         }
```

If I try to print the Before date I see "optional":

> Optional(2018-03-16 10:19:26 +0000)

While the other date looks more normal:

> 2018-03-16 11:19:26 +0000

Comment: Use this `print(beforeDate!)` . Use this

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define `beforeDate`, [`byAdding` returns an optional value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar). If you want a non-optional value, you need to unwrap the optional, like so:

```
let beforeDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: Date())

print(beforeDate) // this is optional

// this is non-optional because you're unwrapping it
if let beforeDate = beforeDate {
  // the date is unwrapped and no longer optional
  // now you can do what you need to do with it
}
```

When you add the `!` after `beforeDate`, you're said to be doing a force unwrap. If you unwrap a value that's not there, your app will crash.

You'll also want to make sure you have an entry for the `NSMotionUsageDescription` key in your Info.plist file.

Lastly, if you're not already doing so, you might want to run your app a physical device that has steps logged. If you're in simulator, you're not going to have any steps logged, which could explain the `nil` value for steps.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this is very clear. Although, I get a "nil" amount of steps. Is it maybe because the date I pass to the query is not correct?

Comment: Do you have a key entered in Info.plist for `NSMotionUsageDescription`?

Comment: Yes I do. I inserted it at the beginning of the project. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That was a good idea. I was already running on my phone which has steps logged. I'll try to make a specific question now that the one regarding the date has been replied. Thanks again for your help.